# How to track 1 object instead of multiple?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, opencv

I wish to alter this code in order to track a singular large object in motion, i.e. a person, when I run the code as is, the display will track a person as multiple objects rather than as one singular object. 
Ignoring the firebase, I want to draw the rectangle around the entire object, rather than parts of the object. 
Also, I wish to change the orientation of the lines set on the display from horizontal to vertical, please?

```
import datetime
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np

from firebase import firebase

# global variables
width = 0
height = 0
EntranceCounter = 0
ExitCounter = 0
min_area = 3000  # Adjust ths value according to your usage
_threshold = 70  # Adjust ths value according to your usage
OffsetRefLines = 150  # Adjust ths value according to your usage


# Check if an object in entering in monitored zone
def check_entrance_line_crossing(y, coor_y_entrance, coor_y_exit):
    abs_distance = abs(y - coor_y_entrance)

    if ((abs_distance <= 2) and (y < coor_y_exit)):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


# Check if an object in exitting from monitored zone
def check_exit_line_crossing(y, coor_y_entrance, coor_y_exit):
    abs_distance = abs(y - coor_y_exit)

    if ((abs_distance <= 2) and (y > coor_y_entrance)):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# force 640x480 webcam resolution
camera.set(3, 640)
camera.set(4, 480)

ReferenceFrame = None

# Frames may discard while adjusting to light
for i in range(0, 20):
    (grabbed, Frame) = camera.read()

while True:
    (grabbed, Frame) = camera.read()
    height = np.size(Frame, 0)
    width = np.size(Frame, 1)

    # if cannot grab a frame, this program ends here.
    if not grabbed:
        break

    # gray-scale and Gaussian blur filter applying
    GrayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(Frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    GrayFrame = cv2.GaussianBlur(GrayFrame, (21, 21), 0)

    if ReferenceFrame is None:
        ReferenceFrame = GrayFrame
        continue

    # Background subtraction and image manipulation
    FrameDelta = cv2.absdiff(ReferenceFrame, GrayFrame)
    FrameThresh = cv2.threshold(FrameDelta, _threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # Dilate image and find all the contours
    FrameThresh = cv2.dilate(FrameThresh, None, iterations=2)
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(FrameThresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    qtty_of_count = 0

    # plot reference lines (entrance and exit lines)
    coor_y_entrance = (height // 2) - OffsetRefLines
    coor_y_exit = (height // 2) + OffsetRefLines
    cv2.line(Frame, (0, coor_y_entrance), (width, coor_y_entrance), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.line(Frame, (0, coor_y_exit), (width, coor_y_exit), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # check all found count
    for c in cnts:
        # if a contour has small area, it'll be ignored
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < min_area:
            continue

        qtty_of_count = qtty_of_count + 1
        app = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://finalyearproj-caa49.firebaseio.com/', None)
       ## result = app.post('/people', {'count': qtty_of_count})##
        update = app.put('/people', "count", qtty_of_count)
        print("Updated value in FB" + str(update))
        # draw an rectangle "around" the object
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(Frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # find object's centroid
        coor_x_centroid = (x + x + w) // 2
        coor_y_centroid = (y + y + h) // 2
        ObjectCentroid = (coor_x_centroid, coor_y_centroid)
        cv2.circle(Frame, ObjectCentroid, 1, (0, 0, 0), 5)

        if (check_entrance_line_crossing(coor_y_centroid, coor_y_entrance, coor_y_exit)):
            EntranceCounter += 1

        if (check_exit_line_crossing(coor_y_centroid, coor_y_entrance, coor_y_exit)):
            ExitCounter += 1

        print("Total countours found: " + str(qtty_of_count))

# Write entrance and exit counter values on frame and shows it
        cv2.putText(Frame, "Entrances: {}".format(str(EntranceCounter)), (10, 50),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (250, 0, 1), 2)
        cv2.putText(Frame, "Exits: {}".format(str(ExitCounter)), (10, 70),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Original Frame", Frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Add a global variable min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y starting with co-ordinates in the middle of your screen, and then in your for c in cnts loop: check to see if the x and y co-ordinates are lower than min_x/min_y or larger than max_x/max_y. Then move the cv2.rectangle outside of the for loop to draw to the min/max co-ordinates.

Comment: @BobDole would you have a code example to support this?

Comment: I don't have a working example to build off of since your code is very specific to libraries and hardware I don't have setup at the moment, but generally speaking you're just doing some basic if statements to see the outer bounds of all of the detected objects. Then you draw one rectangle outside of the for loop based on that, it's only a few lines of code. Though I was wrong about the the initial global values. Don't set them to the center at first, set them to the dimensions of the first object then go from there.